# Setting a default language for a textarea to Korean

Tags: javascript, css, html, textarea

I am looking to set the default language of a textarea to Korean. Does anyone know how this can be done? Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by default language?

Comment: Right now when I press it, it inputs in English.  I may have to switch the onclick event to Korean characters

Comment: I think that depends on your browser language. Can you send a printscreen I would like to see it please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default language for HTML input\`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773120/set-default-language-for-html-inputs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i change default language and font of html textarea and disable other languages and font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120236/how-can-i-change-default-language-and-font-of-html-textarea-and-disable-other-la)